# Primality test for $\frac{(10 \cdot 2^n)^m-1}{10 \cdot 2^n-1} - 2$ and $\frac{(10 \cdot 2^n)^m+1}{10 \cdot 2^n+1} - 2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Here is what I observed:

**For $\frac{(10 \cdot 2^n)^m-1}{10 \cdot 2^n-1} - 2$** :

Let $N$ = $\frac{(10 \cdot 2^n)^m-1}{10 \cdot 2^n-1} - 2$ :
when $m$ is a number $m \ge 3$ and $n \ge 0$.

Let the sequence $S_i=2 \cdot T_{10 \cdot 2^n}(S_{i-1}/2)$ where $T_{n}(x)$ is the Chebyshev's polynomial of the first kind with $S_0=L_{10 \cdot 2^n}$ where $L_{n}$ is the $n_{th}$ Lucas number. Then $N$ is prime if and only if $S_{m-1} \equiv L_{30 \cdot 2^n-2}\pmod{N}$.

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9T7sOgzAM3PMZTDEP0YQuyPUnlIUdqaRBRCIJAtSqf99UgKg6dLJ9d76zHZ2RWSpLZBVxLk6xbBw0NhOQb1NoM4msps603t2UMgeR_GKJAGRqmUgge_Zm0DwMFwp-aU1Xf-cyHv2get2-5l4_tq00sLmEtAIM8oQ-JqbjNRE_Aoo1tPgOLfZDIB0n4xb-5wXAVRKFYnW0b0TK29HPZgkQ4Bs16E2K&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

**For $\frac{(10 \cdot 2^n)^m+1}{10 \cdot 2^n+1} - 2$** :

Let $N$ = $\frac{(10 \cdot 2^n)^m+1}{10 \cdot 2^n+1} - 2$ :
when $m$ is a odd number $m \ge 3$ and $n \ge 0$.

Let the sequence $S_i=2 \cdot T_{10 \cdot 2^n}(S_{i-1}/2)$ where $T_{n}(x)$ is the Chebyshev's polynomial of the first kind with $S_0=L_{10 \cdot 2^n}$ where $L_{n}$ is the $n_{th}$ Lucas number. Then $N$ is prime if and only if $S_{m-1} \equiv L_{30 \cdot 2^n+2}\pmod{N}$.

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9T80KwjAMvvcxdmrWjtkO8VDzCO6y-8DVjhVsO7ah-PZG3BAUPCXfXz4SURsWcH8wrEbO1S7XbYQ2CAXlimgtyNRg77sUz9b6VSgUiG-OzIbZZUJl2H3wV8cJHDEUSjZ4Sheu8zFd7eC6xzy425qSpJYaZA2G7AJfR3zPG0T-Kai2AvHDVQBynHxc-J8XwLwtGY3gsi2R2RTGNPuFKDBPJ5RNdg==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Is there a way to explain this? I don't know how to start for proving it. If you found a counterexample please tell me.

Comment: In the implementation, it's better to move `Mod` operation to the initialization of `S` - like `S=Mod(fibonacci(10*2^n-1)+fibonacci(10*2^n+1),N)`. Computing Chebyshev polynomials on residue classes works pretty well. Check this out: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=bliyah

Answer (score 5):

It's often the case with such tests that the "only if" part is more or less easy to prove, while the "if" part is inaccessible for proving or disproving. Below I prove the "only if" part, ie. assuming that $N$ is prime.

First notice that Chebyshev polynomials appear here just for efficient computation of [Lucas number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number)
$$S_{m-1} = L_{(10\cdot 2^n)^m}.$$

Since $N\equiv -1\pmod{10}$, we have that the [period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period) of $L_k$ modulo $N$ divides $N-1$. It remains to notice that
$$(10\cdot 2^n)^m\ =\ (N+2)(10\cdot 2^n\mp 1)\pm 1\ \equiv\ 30\cdot 2^n\mp 2\pmod{N-1},$$
implying that $S_{m-1} = L_{(10\cdot 2^n)^m} \equiv L_{30\cdot 2^n\mp 2}\pmod{N}$.

---

PS. As for the "if" part - since its conclusion is based on a single congruence, we get an analog of Lucas preudoprimality test, which is known to have [false positives](https://oeis.org/A005845). However, here we are restricted to exponentially growing numbers, where finding false positives becomes much harder if feasible.