# Generalized primality test for Mersenne and Wagstaff numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Inspired by the paper "Chebyshev polynomials and higher order Lucas Lehmer algorithm" by Kok Seng Chu, I think a made a generalized primality test for Mersenne and Wagstaff numbers.

Here is what I observed :

Let $N = \frac{-a^p-1}{-a-1}$ with $a = 2$ for Wagstaff numbers and $a = -2$ for Mersenne numbers.

Let the sequence $S_i = 2 \cdot T_{|a|}(S_{i-1}/2)$ where $T_{n}(x)$ is the Chebyshev's polynomial of the first kind with $S_0 = 7$.

Then $N$ is prime if $S_{p-1} \equiv 2 \cdot T_{|a|-(-|a|/a)-(-1)^{((p-|a|/a)/2)}}(3/2) (mod N)$

You can run the test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtj7FuxCAQRPuT7h9WrhYH5ECKFGTzB3Hj9nQS9nEyEj6QIYny91n7ohRRGmYYDQ-NI2UsnE7QOiAwkFZQpj0eMunne768lwqjh7yGxYO7XeAVtkZPqNw5Ky06Niz2eIj0xOdAb-mCUfZbNNWVNOvnHKJHvr1QlgOZNqc4zX78KrP_QDcWdEJqOXRGWG490A4smmK4VtyAg_r3keLfd9PtXoszYlb4mwkmMjhu0osNGq7IXHqUPOlW8c8MYe9xsw9uxE-rmdKSUwmVI2G_AQMYVjg=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Is there a way to proving this? I don't know how to start for proving it.

In the original Lucas-Lehmer test, it's known than if $p \equiv 3 (mod 4)$, you can use $S_0 = 3$ instead of $4$.

But I don't how to prove it for the generalized primality test.

If you found a counterexample please tell me.

EDIT: The test seems to work too for $a=3$ or $a=-3$ with $S_0=52$ and $N$ is prime if $S_{p-1} \equiv 2 \cdot T_{|a|-(-|a|/a)-(-1)^{((N-|a|/a)/2)}}(4/2) (mod N)$

You can run the test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtj8FuwyAQRO-R8g8rnxYX5GLnRrd_UF98jSJhh8hIOCBDW_Xvu3ajHqpemGE0PDSWOgPnM9QWCDqIK6iuPh4SnR758p4LjA7S6hcH9n6FV2i50RMqe0lKi4YNizkeAp34HOgtXjHIfoumspJm_Zx9cMi3F0pyoLZOMUyzG7_y7D7QjhmtkFoOTSsMt55oB2ZNwd8KbsBB_ftI8e-7aXavxQWxV_ibCSYyOGzSiw3qb8hcepY86V7wzwxhfuJqH1yJR6ua4pJi9oUjYb4BwoVV7A==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

Comment: This yet another variation of Lucas preudoprimality test. See https://mathoverflow.net/q/422634

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks for your interest for the question. Maybe you could help me. For a=+- 2, the seed S0=7 $3^2-2$ seems to works,. For a = +- 3, S0=52 $4^2-3\cdot4$ seems to works too (If I choose N instead of p in the sequence as I write it). But for a = +- 7, $S0=2T_{7}(29/2)$ doesn't work at all, I get both false negative and postive. But it seems it works with with S0=710647 = $2T_{7}(7/2)$. I try to understand how to choose the good seed for a general test. But for the moment I can't find a general formula for the seed but I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Your formulas are overengineered and do not quite match the code. Essentially you can take $S_0 = 1 = L_1$ (Lucas number) and then consider two cases depending on whether $N\equiv \pm1\pmod{10}$ or $N\equiv \pm3\pmod{10}$. In the former case, we can check $S_{p+1} \equiv L_{a^2}\pmod{N}$, while in the latter case we can check $S_{p+1} \equiv L_{-a(a+2)}\pmod{N}$. (Notice the index $p+1$ here.)